# Rename folder under wtpwebapps but not changing project name

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, directory, rename

I have created a dynamic web project (let's call it ABC) and using Tomcat as web server,
when I start tomcat, folder ABC will be created under wtpwebapps, the path is like  this: org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\ABC

Is it possible to rename ABC to AB without changing project name?
So when I start the client, the URL can be localhost:8080\AB instead of localhost:8080\ABC

Comment: This is definitely possible with Tomcat itself... not sure about within Eclipse.

Comment: figured out there is a setting of Eclipse, right click > Web Project Settings, Change the value of Context root

Answer (score 0):

Right click the Eclipse project and choose Properties > Web Project Settings. Then change the value of field "Context root".

(This answer is copied from MIT's comment above.)